# Show media in Gridview as Instagram

Tags: android

I am creating app like Instagram and want to show user's all media in GridView as Instagram,when we click on user's name we get all the information of user,i am able to show user's information,but i don't know how to show user's post images in gridview.I am using this api to get media

"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN"

but i don't know how to show image in gridview which is coming from server.

Comment: you can use Picaso for display images from your server to your imageview

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: yes,i am using UniversalImageLoader but i don't know how to code for getting image from server in Adapter in getView

Comment: Try glide, it has the simplest code to load images from server. If you want further help, upload the code of your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Use `RecylerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` /`GridLayoutManager`.

see this for example http://www.android-examples.com/android-recyclerview-with-gridview-gridlayoutmanager